# How to write the below SQL queries?

Tags: sql

Consider 3 columns like below. I need to get columns having same col1 with col2 values as 1 and 2 and col3 have 2 different values for col2 where col1 will be same for col2 and col3

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A          1    IND
A          2    IND
A          3    IND
B          1    IND
B          2    PAK
B          3    IND
B          4    IND
C          1    IND
C          2    IND
C          3    PAK
C          4    PAK
D          1    IND
D          2    PAK
E          1    PAK
E          2    SA
```

The result will be as given below

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
B          1    IND
B          2    PAK
D          1    IND
D          2    PAK
E          1    PAK
E          2    SA
```

Here is what I tried for col1 and col2:

```
select col1 from your_table
where col2 in (1,2)
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) > 1
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I got how to obtain 1st and 2 nd column but got confused with the third column. Here is what 1 tried for col1 and col2                                                           select col1
from your_table where col2 in (1,2)
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) > 1

Comment: When you tried your attempt, what did not work with it? What results did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows with 3 and 4 in Col2 can be ignored as per your request so

- Self Join on col1
- Filter to col2 in (1, 2)
- col3 is different

Like this

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   MyTable M1
   JOIN
   MyTable M2 ON M1.COl1 = M2.COl1
WHERE
   M1.Col2 IN (1, 2)
   AND
   M2.Col2 IN (1, 2)
   AND
   M2.Col3 <> M1.COl3
```

Comment: @gbn, As per Microsoft Guidelines, more than five tables are not allowed to join in SQL Server. Is it correct? If not correct, as per your perspective how many tables are allowed to join in SQL Server for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this is aggregation.  The following gets the column A values that meet your conditions:

```
select col1
from t
where col2 in (1, 2)
group by col1
having min(col3) <> max(col3);
```

If you want to get the original rows, there are multiple ways.  Apart from obvious ones (such as `in`, `exists`, and `join`), you can use window functions:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (select t.*,
             min(col3) over (partition by col1) as mincol3,
             max(col3) over (partition by col1) as maxcol3
      from t
      where col2 in (1, 2)
     ) t
where mincol3 <> maxcol3;
```

Comment: Thanks...but i am not getting the expected result !

Comment: Hi @Halfer sorry..i did not captured the result as i have received what i expected from the above comment.....thanks for the help.